# Set initial hour to present in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

in full Calendar - is there a way to set the "landing hour" of the widget? 
Currently the first visible hour is 06:00 - 
if I want the first hour to be seen -15:00 - but I don't won't to lose the hours before (the user still can scroll up and see them) - but the most important data is usually from 15:00 and up..is that can be achieved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For version 2 you can use [`scrollTime` option](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/scrollTime/):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        right: 'agendaWeek'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    scrollTime :  "15:00:00" //3pm
});
```

For version 1 you can use the `firstHour` option when initializing:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        right: 'agendaWeek'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    firstHour: 15
});
```

Please see this jsFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gTzkU/. Of course the calendar cannot be scrolled down far enough for 15:00 to be the very first hour shown, but the result for that particular time is that the calendar is scrolled down as far as it will go. Perhaps this is a better illustration, with the calendar set to start at 9:00: http://jsfiddle.net/5p6yN/.

Documentation can be found here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/firstHour/.

Comment: Worth adding is that this is the solution for version 1 of FullCalendar. For version 2 of FullCalendar, use scrollTime, which could be set to '15:00:00' - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/scrollTime/

Answer (score 0):

For version 5, you have these options:

- scrollTime, for set the time to init scroll
- slotMinTime, initial hour in table
- slotMaxTime, final hour in table

with format Duration ('00:00:00').

Beware of aspectRatio, the automatic height will extends the last row of the table. I suggest to change aspectRatio to 2, for a table between 9am and 22 pm, for desktop view.